# reading strings from text file using java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

```
col1 col2 col3
abc 22 rome
xyz 11 spain
rome 12 uae
```

want to read this text file, every column values as individual objects to compare between any two object of those column.

here is my code, suggest some proper modification

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication3;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try{
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new FileReader("exemple_1.txt"));

        List<String> ls1 = new ArrayList<String>(); /* to store ClosedSet values */
        List<String> ls2 = new ArrayList<String>(); /* to store Support values */ 
        List<String> ls3 = new ArrayList<String>(); /* to store ObjectList vaules */

        while(s.hasNext()){
            String[] str = s.next().split("\t");
            String s1 = str[0].trim();      /* takes ClosedSet vaues to read */
            String s2 = str[1].trim();      /* takes Support vaues to read */
            String s3= str[2].trim();       /* takes ObjectList vaues to read */

            if(!"Col1".equals(s1)){ /* skip first line */
                ls1.add(s1);
            }
            if(!"col2".equals(s2)){     /* skip first line */
                ls2.add(s2);
            }
            if(!"col3".equals(s3)){ /* skip first line */
                ls3.add(s3);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(ls2);        /* print support values */

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } /* catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   */
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `s.next()` (in `s.next().split("\t")`) does? Also what is your question/problem you are facing?

Comment: reading elements to find the particular character "\t" for splitting.and the code shows some runtime error while executing

Comment: Which part of documentation of that method makes you think so?

Comment: Also "shows some runtime error while executing" doesn't help us help you. You need to be more precise (I suspect some kind of index-out-of-bounds exception, in which case you should go back to my first comment).

Comment: throws IOException in scanner class object most probably

Comment: [edit] your question and include stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the file line by line, use `s.hasNextLine()` and `s.nextLine()`. Also, `equals(...)` is case sensitive, you've used `!"Col1".equals(s1)` instead of `!"col1".equals(s1)`

Comment: even its not working too, 'could not find or load main class' how to resolve it?

Comment: @user6117629 [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: have solved it guys...actually the package was misplaced